# Drawdown duration

Tags: r

How can I get the duration of the drawdowns in a zoo serie?
the drawdowns can be calculated with cummax(mydata)-mydata.  Whenever this value is above zero I have a drawdown.
The Drawdown is the measure of the decline from a historical peak (maximum).
It lasts till this value is reached again.

Comment: Hello

When I use findDrawdowns with my zoo series it says: Error in if (thisSign == priorSign) { : 

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

How can I solve it? I've tried with chron and POSIXct, and converting to timeseries but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `PerformanceAnalytics` package [has several functions](http://braverock.com/brian/R/PerformanceAnalytics/html/chart.Drawdown.html) to do this operation.

```
> library(PerformanceAnalytics)
> data(edhec)
> dd <- findDrawdowns(edhec[,"Funds of Funds", drop=FALSE])
> dd$length
 [1]  3  3  6  5  4 11 14  5  2 10  2  6  3  2  4  9  2  2 13  8  5  5  4  2  7
[26]  6 11  3  2 23
```

As a side note, if you have two dates in a time series and need to know the time between them, just use `diff`.  You can also use [the `lubridate` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html).

Comment: I'm sorry for posting my comments as answers.
I've used performanceAnalytics Drawdowns but it doens't work for me, even with the sample data supplied.


"Error en checkData(R) : The data cannot be converted into a time series. If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'. Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'."

Anyway, how can I calculate the drawdown durations without using this package?

thanks